Substituting variables into interpolated function
I am quite new to Mathematica so I sincerely apologise if this is a simple question or someone has asked it before. Given the code below:
M = 23.58/1000;
l = 0.9;
Ms = ((2*2.02)/1000) Sqrt[l^2 - 0.4^2];
NN = 10; 
dl = Sqrt[l^2 - 0.4^2]/NN;
g = 9.81;
m[n_] := If[n == NN, M, Ms/(NN - 1)];
r[n_, t_] := 
  Sum[UnitVector[3, 1]*dl Sin[\[Theta][i, t]] - 
    UnitVector[3, 3]*dl Cos[\[Theta][i, t]], {i, n}];
rdot[n_, t_] := D[r[n, t], t];
tt[t_] := (1/2) Sum[m[n]*Total[rdot[n, t]^2], {n, NN}];
vv[t_] := g*Sum[m[n]*r[n, t][[3]], {n, NN}];
ll[t_] := tt[t] - vv[t];
rr[t_] := (1/2) kvc*
   Sum[(D[\[Theta][n, t], t] - D[\[Theta][n - 1, t], t])^2, {n, 2, 
     NN}];
airdamp[t_] := (1/2) cd*Total[rdot[NN, t]^2];
eqLag[k_] := 
  D[D[ll[t], D[\[Theta][k, t], t]], t] - 
    D[ll[t], \[Theta][k, t]] == -D[rr[t], D[\[Theta][k, t], t]];
lastpend := 
  D[D[ll[t], D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]], t] - 
    D[ll[t], \[Theta][NN, t]] == -D[airdamp[t], 
      D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]] - D[rr[t], D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]];
eqs = Join[Table[eqLag[k], {k, NN - 1}], {lastpend} ];
initialData = 
  Flatten[Table[{\[Theta][k, 0] == ArcTan[0.423/(-0.723)], 
     Derivative[0, 1][\[Theta]][k, 0] == 0}, {k, NN}]];
model[cdd_?NumberQ, kvcc_?NumberQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[Flatten@{eqs, initialData} /. {cd -> cdd, kvc -> kvcc},
    ArcTan[(dl Sum[Sin[\[Theta][k, t]], {k, NN}])/(
    dl Sum[Cos[\[Theta][k, t]], {k, NN}])], {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

When I input dummy values into model, for example
model[5/100000,1/1000]

I get an expression that involves multiple interpolation functions. May i know how i can input a specific time into these interpolation functions, to get the result from model? Any help would be greatly appreciated. My first thought was this:
model[5/100000,1/1000][2]

where t=2, but this doesnt seem to achieve the intended outcome.

I didn't analyze your code at all, but I did copy-paste it and evaluate it. The result of evaluating model[5/100000, 1/1000] was a large expression that included bits like this:
InterpolationFunction[...bunch of data for the function...][t]

So, the application of the function to arguments is already there, it's just that the argument is the undefined symbol t. If what you want is for those  InterpolationFunction sub-expressions to evaluate with the value 2 in place of t, then you can just do replacements:
model[5/100000, 1/1000] /. t -> 2
(* -0.42159 *)


Ah yes. Thank you that works. Sorry I'm just a bit new to mathematica

You could also try
model[cdd_?NumberQ, kvcc_?NumberQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[Flatten@{eqs, initialData} /. {cd -> cdd, kvc -> kvcc},
    Function[t, 
    Evaluate@
     ArcTan[(dl Sum[Sin[\[Theta][k, t]], {k, NN}])/(dl Sum[
          Cos[\[Theta][k, t]], {k, NN}])]], {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

Now model gives a pure function
model[5/100000, 1/1000][2]  (*-0.42159*)

